# Openbyurl not working for different tabs in the same sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet with two different tabs in it. When I pass the link of the second tab, the below code always brings the content of the first tab in the sheet. New to appscript programming, any leads would be appreciated!

```
 const currentSheetName = sheet.getSheetName();
 if (currentSheetName == "AAA")
 {  
   var sheetData = sheet.getRange('A1:A50').getValues();    
   for(var input=1;input<sheetData.length;input++)  
   {     
     var newURL = sheetData[input][0];
     var cellrow = input+1;
     if (newURL != "")
     {
      try{
        var url = sheet.getRange(cellrow,1).getRichTextValue().getLinkUrl();
        if (url != "") 
        {
          var dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);  
        }
        else{
          var dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(newURL);
        }
       var job = dataSheet.getRange('M9').getValue();
    }
  }
```

}

Comment: Not working is not a very useful problem.  Do some debugging on your own and figure out what's not working.  You have to learn to debug your own cocde.

Comment: I did the debugging before posting the question - openbyUrl does not accept the differnet tabs in the same spreadsheet, rather it pulls only the contents of the first tab.

Comment: How do you know it's not working?

Comment: When i print the url (after try block), it prints the url passed in the sheet but after openbyurl, it brings the contents of the first sheet rather getting the contents from the passed url.

Comment: openByUrl() just opens up the spreadsheet and the first sheet on the left is always the default tab.  You could specifiy a sheet name in the range or call the sheet by name

Answer (score 0):

`openByUrl()` returns a Spreadsheet, not a Sheet. You can use `getSheetByName()` or similar to get the actual sheet.

Answer (score 0):

#### Structure of the Spreadsheet service

In general the structure of the data in the Apps Script Spreadsheet service is:

> `SpreadsheetApp` > `Spreadsheet` > `Sheet` > `Range` > Data

Which is like:

> Service > File > Sheet > Selection > Data

Hence the regular snippet you see at the beginning of many scripts:

```
ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("<ID>")
sh = ss.getSheetByName("<SHEET NAME>")
rng = sh.getRange("<RANGE>")
data = rng.getValues()
```

Though as you have found, calling `getRange` on a Spreadsheet object does actually return a range. It will *usually* default to the first sheet in the spreadsheet. Though it is advisable to always explicitly assign the sheet, even if the spreadsheet only contains one sheet.

#### References

Services and methods of:

- [SpreadsheetApp service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)
- [spreadsheet object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet)
- [sheet object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)
- [range object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)